# I need to get a list of ID's from a record table whose child records all are inactive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a list of all InventionId’s where all their related patentId’s are set to inactive

Tables:

Record
I have a table called Record which has a column called RecordID. The column contains both PatentID and InventionID. The InventionID is the parent to the PatentID. It also contains a column called StatusTypeID.

StatusTypeName
In order to get the active status (IsActive column) I need to join Record.StatusTypeID to StatusTypeName.ID.

Invention
I have another table called Invention which contains the InventionID.

Patent
I have another table called Patent which contains both the PatentID and the InventionID.

This is what I’ve tried but I’m still getting Inventions that contain patents that are still active.

```
SELECT RecordId,b.RecordTypeId,c.StatusTypeId, c.StatusTypeName, c.IsActive, i.SecondaryStatusTypeId
FROM Record a
JOIN RefRecordType b
ON a.RecordTypeId = b.RecordTypeId
JOIN RefStatusType c
ON c.StatusTypeId = a.StatusTypeId
JOIN Invention i
ON a.RecordId= i.InventionId

WHERE a.RecordTypeId = 19 AND RecordId NOT IN
(
SELECT PatentId
    FROM Patent p
    JOIN Record r
    ON r.RecordId = p.PatentId
    JOIN RefStatusType rst
    ON r.StatusTypeId = rst.StatusTypeId
    JOIN Invention
    ON i.InventionId = p.InventionId
    WHERE  rst.IsActive = 1  
    )

    ORDER BY a.RecordId
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: _I need to get a list of all InventionId’s_ The way this is written implies you need a list of "inventions"; that suggests you should start with that table. "Record" (a crap name for a table) is an intersection table to support a M:M relationship between invention and patent though that seems to be a logic fault based on your writing. And given that Patent and Invention do not logically share the same ID value, the statement "The column contains both PatentID and InventionID" seem logically suspicious. Is it too late to reconsider your schema design?

Comment: Unfortunately its not something I can change.  I guess its a good learning experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that your inner join to Invention is missing the alias, which means that refereces to `i` in the inner query are actually referencing the outer Invention table, making this an unintended correlated query.

If that is not the issue, I suggest that you switch your logic to use a `NOT EXISTS(...)` condition, which can more directly test for your required conditions.  Something like:

```
WHERE a.RecordTypeId = 19
AND NOT EXISTS (
    -- any related patentId which is set to active
)
```

I wasn't able to follow how your original inner query implements "all InventionId’s where all their related patentId’s are set to inactive", so I wrote the following as my best guess reinterpretation:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Patent p2
    JOIN Record r2 ON r2.RecordId = p2.PatentId
    JOIN RefStatusType rst2 ON rst2.StatusTypeId = r2.StatusTypeId
    WHERE p2.InventionId = i.InventionId
    AND rst2.IsActive = 1
)
```

This reinterprets "all their related patentId’s are set to inactive" to "no related Patents have any associated Record whose status is active".

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to work on  it now. I appreciate it.